# freebase - get description of person

Tags: freebase

I have the following MQL query which successfully returns the record for William Shakespeare.

```
[{
  "/type/object/name": null,
  "/type/object/id": "/en/william_shakespeare"
}]​
```

http://tinyurl.com/cnpma3f

I am trying to get the description attribute. When I add "description": null, I get a 'no description attribute found' error. Yet, looking at the record in freebase, it should be there:

http://www.freebase.com/experimental/topic/standard/en/william_shakespeare

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The topic API aggregates results across a number of Freebase services; the descriptions are stored separately from the other data about a topic and you'll have to use the [text service](http://wiki.freebase.com/wiki/ApiText) to fetch them, rather than MQL directly.

As an aside, you should probably consider changing to the [new Freebase APIs](http://wiki.freebase.com/wiki/Freebase_API); those hosted at (www|api).freebase.com are deprecated and will (allegedly) be turned off in October.